# How to pick number of executors , cores for each executor and executor memory

Tags: pyspark

`10 Node` cluster, each machine has `16 cores` and `126.04 GB` of RAM

Application input dataset is around `1TB` with `10-15 files` and there is some aggregation(`groupBy`)

Job will run using Yarn as resource scheduler

My Question how to pick num-executors, executor-memory, executor-core, driver-memory, driver-cores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use this tool - http://spark-configuration.luminousmen.com/ , for profiling my Spark Jobs , the process does take some hit and try , but it helps in the longer run

Additionally you can understand how Spark Memory works - https://luminousmen.com/post/dive-into-spark-memory